# if...if else..or else how to do an output for them

Tags: c#

My teacher wants me to use a switch statement and im new to this I actually have two questions on this please help.
first is:

Use a switch statement to output the following based on an int input that corresponds to an exhibit at the zoo.  Prompt the user with “Please enter the exhibit0+363 number: “

```
Input   output

1       Polar Bear
2       Penguin
3       Moose
4       Reindeer
5       Deer
6       Turtle
7       Lion
8       Fish
9       Bug
```

I don't understand

and the second is:

Use an if…else-if…else statement to output the following based on an int temp that is input by the user Prompt the user with “Please enter a temperature”.

```
Input   output
< 10    Polar Bear
< 20    Penguin
< 40    Moose
< 50    Reindeer
< 60    Deer
< 70    Turtle
< 80    Lion
< 90    Fish
Default Bug
```

or this question ha

help

This is my code for the first one so far and its gives me error messages
im not sure if this is what he wants for the question

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
     class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
          Console.WriteLine("exhibit0-360");
            }
     {
          switch (case)
                 // The following switch section causes an error.
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("polar bear");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("penquin");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("moose");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("reindeer");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("deer");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine("turtle");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Console.Write("lion");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Console.WriteLine("fish");
                    break;

                case 9:
                    Console.WriteLine("bug");
                    break;

             }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Share the code you've written.

Comment: "I don't understand" is not a question. Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Code helps to understand your problem. Personally, I don't understand `'exhibit0+363 number'`

Comment: This question is too vague and will likely be closed. My advice: first, if you need help, talk to your professor or TA. Second, read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/. Third, read the documentation for the switch statement and see if you understand the examples. Once you have a *specific* question, ask it here.

Comment: [switch (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Comment: you missed the "user input" part.  **that** is what you want to use: `switch(userInput)`

Comment: I just tried that and its giving me an error message that says Error namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Answer (score 0):

For the if else statement question you're going to want to write a simple user input that asks your user to input a temperature. Once you input that value your program should check the user given value against the values that correlate to each animal. If so and so temp than this else it will be this and to end your statement put not valid temperature if it doesn't correlate.

Comment: instructions followed with a sample would be better

Answer (score 0):

class Program

```
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the exhibit number: ");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        int caseSwitch = int.Parse(str);
        switch (caseSwitch) 
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("polar bear ");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("penquin ");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("moose ");
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("reindeer ");
                break;
            case 5:
                Console.WriteLine("deer ");
                break;
            case 6:
                Console.WriteLine("turtle ");
                break;
            case 7:
                Console.Write("lion ");
                break;
            case 8:
                Console.WriteLine("fish ");
                break;

            case 9:
                Console.WriteLine("bug ");
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you provide an answer to a question, please try to write a few words instead of just publishing a code example! Also try to format your code right.

Best regards and a good time here!

Answer (score 0):

class Program

```
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a temperature: "); 

        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 

        if (temp >= 90) { Console.WriteLine("fish"); } 

        else if (temp >= 80) { Console.WriteLine("Lion"); } 

        else if (temp >= 70) { Console.WriteLine("Turle"); } 

        else if (temp >= 60) { Console.WriteLine("Deer"); } 

        else if (temp >= 50) { Console.WriteLine("Reindeer"); } 

        else if (temp >= 40) { Console.WriteLine("Moose"); } 

        else if (temp >= 20) { Console.WriteLine("Penguin"); } 

        else if (temp >= 10) { Console.WriteLine("Polar Bear"); } 

        else { Console.WriteLine("Bug"); }
    }
}
```

}